# HTML wont open; Not sure what I am missing

Tags: javascript, html

This is the link to the viewable example from the book;http://beginningjs.com/examples/ch2_example7.html

This is my code saved locally; Not sure why it wont load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Chapter 2, Example 7</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                var myString = "56.02 degrees centigrade";
                var myInt;
                var myFloat;

                document.write{"\"" + myString + "\" is + "\" +     parseInt(myString, 10) +
                 "as an interger" + "<br/>"};

                 myInt = parseInt(myString, 10);
                 document.write("\"" + myString + "\"when converted to an interger equals " + myInt + "<br/>" ); 

                 nyFloat = parseFloat(myString);
                 document.write( "\"" + myString + "\" when converted to a floating point number equals " + myFloat);

                 document.write(myString);

            </script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: The first `document.write` should have parentheses `()` after it instead of curly braces `{}`.

Comment: Also, you have `nyFloat` instead of `myFloat` on the third to last line.

Comment: Thanks but its still not loading or any of the other examples from this book

Comment: Don't know why that is since we can't see the path you're using to load the page, and we don't know where the file is stored on your computer.

Comment: Go through line by line and make sure it all looks correct. Your problem lies within a typing error.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Javascript\DataConversion.html ....could the path be creating an issue?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with windows, but try putting `file:///` at the start of that url.

Comment: Also first critical step in learning javascript for web pages is how to view errors thrown in browser console...and interpret them

Comment: Have you learned about the developer tools/console? Press F12 (or Ctrl+Shift+I) in your browser, it will open a box with useful information, and will tell if there are syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's loaded but your javascript syntax are wrong.
Use parentheses instead of braces on your first document.write. The script is stuck in that line and the rest of your program doesn't execute, that's why the page doesn't show anything.

Answer (score -1):

Okay There is an error in your first `document.write("your string")` line you need to use small () braces instead of curly {} braces every time you use `document.write("your string")`. You have declared variable as `var myFloat;` and then used it as `nyFloat = parseFloat(myString);` which is wrong because of typo in `nyFloat` and `(mystring,10)` to print value 56.02 at the end. so the correct is `myFloat = parseFloat(myString,10);` There is no need to write the last line i.e. `document.Write(myString);` as it is printing the string again at the end. If in future you experience these kind of errors you can see these Javascript errors by using developer tool in your browser and for that you just need to press F12 from your key board as explained in one of comment under your question.

Here is the corrected code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Chapter 2, Example 7</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                var myString = "56.02 degrees centigrade";
                var myInt;
                var myFloat;

                document.write("\"" + myString + "\" is " +    parseInt(myString, 10) + " as an interger" + "<br/>");

                 myInt = parseInt(myString, 10);
                 document.write("\"" + myString + "\" when converted to an interger equals " + myInt + "<br/>" ); 

                 myFloat = parseFloat(myString, 10);

                 document.write("\"" + myString + "\" when converted to a floating point number equals " + myFloat);

                 //document.write(myString);

            </script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Describe in detail everything that you fixed.

Comment: @Aamerallous please put that on the answer, preferably explaining why, not just what. The asker is clearly a beginner, and as one it's great to know what he's doing, not just copy-paste something that works.

Comment: @RickRosario If it helps you then mark it as answer.